# VBAProject of another workbook stays open after that workbook is closed via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, adodb

I'm importing data via VBA from another workbook, which contains a data table that is the output of a PowerQuery query. Within my code, I first refresh said query before selecting a subset of the data using an ADO recordset. While the data import works fine, Excel throws a run-time error when I run the script a second time without closing Excel between runs:

[image]

While investigating this issue, I noticed that the VBA project of the source workbook stays open, even after I programmatically close that workbook:

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
Public Sub ReadIn()

'-----------------------------------------
'   open workbook
'-----------------------------------------
Const STR_PATH_WKB As String = "C:\TEMP1\test\Input_XLSX.xlsx"

Dim wkbSource As Workbook

Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(STR_PATH_WKB)

'-----------------------------------------
'   Refresh Source Data Query
'-----------------------------------------
Dim lsoSource As ListObject

Set lsoSource = wkbSource.Sheets(2).ListObjects(1)
Call lsoSource.QueryTable.Refresh(BackgroundQuery:=False)

'-----------------------------------------
'   get data
'-----------------------------------------
Dim strQuery As String, strConnection As String
Dim con As Object
Dim rcs As Object

strQuery = "SELECT * FROM <TABLE> " & _
           "WHERE [ID] < 5"
strQuery = Replace(strQuery, "<TABLE>", "[" & lsoSource.Parent.Name & "$" & lsoSource.Range.Address(False, False) & "]")

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rcs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strConnection = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & wkbSource.FullName & ";HDR=Yes';"
Call con.Open(strConnection)

Call rcs.Open(Source:=strQuery, ActiveConnection:=con)

'-----------------------------
'   Write data to array
'-----------------------------
Dim varData As Variant

If rcs.EOF Then
    varData = Empty
Else
    varData = rcs.GetRows()
End If

'-----------------------------
'   Do stuff
'-----------------------------
' ...

'-----------------------------------------
'   clean up
'-----------------------------------------
Set lsoSource = Nothing

Call rcs.Close
Call con.Close

Set rcs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing

Call wkbSource.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
Set wkbSource = Nothing

Erase varData


MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

I'm working with Office 365, Version 1902.

Comment: Is there a BeforeClose event on the "source workbook" that could be delaying or preventing its close?

Comment: `'   Do stuff` What do you have there?

Comment: @John Joseph: No, there are no events in the source workbook.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: If I run the exact code from the post, I receive the error, so this part should be irrelevant.

Comment: @mcgurck, I'm out of ideas. You might try putting a DoEvents right after your Close command to give the system time to wrap up before setting the object to nothing. Let me know if that helps.

        Call wkbSource.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        DoEvents
        Set wkbSource = Nothing

Comment: @JohnJoseph, unfortunately this didn't work either ...

Comment: @mcgurck, I just don't know, but I have one last thought.  The VBA project that is being held open is associated with a .XLSX file. If you've ever tried closing a .XLSX file to which you've added code, you know that you'll be informed that .XLSX files can't keep that code (only .XLSM files, macro-enabled files can.)  Perhaps this warning condition is blocking the close.  Can you try saving your input file as a .XLSM and running your code again?

Comment: @JohnJoseph, I just tried that, but it didn't help ...